# Rails Nested object Creationg

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, nested

I have a project with the below scenario

Three Objects:

**Client**:The real world client

**User**: The who uses the portal

**Department**: The Client for whome the user works (XYZ.com,ABC.com)

The signup page have: FirstName,username,password,ClientName,Email

Client have only one field value: The client Name
FirstName,username,password,ClientName,Email are of user

Now what I want is to create a Department with ClientName as the Name of the Department and associate the user with the ID of the department.
User have a field department_id

Comment: Even if you cannot post the code, please be clear with your notations. What are your models ? You mention User, Client, Department, what's the difference between a Client and a User ? Does a User `has_many :client` ?

Comment: Even if you are working for a company, the rule of thumb in security is that everything about the implementation can be known as long as the key used for encryption of data remain secure. If you are new to Rails, you're more likely to introduce security vulnerabilities that attackers could easily spot by themselves... just saying.

Comment: Edited the question with much more clarity. About the code is. I am not suppose to copy paste any amount of code out side the office. This is a policy. And my clip boards and activities are watched by the admin

Answer (score 1):

Even with your reformulation, it is still not clear. So I'll go with my own interpretation. ALso, you didn't specify if you were using Mongoid or ActiveRecord. I'll go with a somewhat Mongoid style as it produces clean modelisation, but feel free to replace with ActiveRecord stuff.

Models

```
class User
  has_one :department
  has_one :client
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :client
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :department

  field :first_name
  field :password
  field :username
  field :email

class Client
  belongs_to :user

  field :name

class Department
  belongs_to :user
  field :name
```

your_controller.rb

```
def new
  @user = User.new
  @user.client = Client.new
  @user.department = Department.new
end

def create
  if @user = User.create(user_params)
    redirect_to @user
  else
    render 'new'
  end
end

private
  def user_params
    # Set department.name as client.name
    if params[:user] and params[:user][:department] and params[:user][:client]
      params[:user][:department][:name] = params[:user][:client][:name]
    end
    params.require[:user].permit(
      :first_name, :password, :username, :email,
      client_attributes: [:id, :name],
      department_attributes: [:id, :name]
    )
  end
```

_form.html.erb

```
<%= form_for :user do |user| %>
  <%= user.text_field(:name) %>
  ...

  <%= user.fields_for :client do |client| %>
    <%= client.text_field(:name) %>
  <% end %>

  <%= user.fields_for :department do |department| %>
    <p class="text-info">A department will be created with the same name as the client</p>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Perfect. Thanks man. I am sorry I couldnt better explain my question. But this was exactly i Was looking. Thank you